# Pycaret Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function

Tags: pycaret

I have setup pycaret 3.0.2 in python 3.10 and I am running it as a .py file. I get this error Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function _ThreadpoolInfo._find_modules_with_dl_iterate_phdr..match_module_callback at 0x7f78b2913640> at the start. There is no issue with the code and is executing as expected however,
I would like to understand the nature of the error and if there is a fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due older version of threadpoolctl refer https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl/issues/131. Fixed this by upgrading the version.

```
pip install --upgrade threadpoolctl
```